# What's being revised here?

Tags: discussion, editing, revisions

See the revision history of this answer:

https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/326031/revisions

7 revisions (so far) and nothing has been added or removed.

What's happening there?

Comment: Having spent the last 5 hours poring through FAQs and posts about when to upvote and downvote (who'd have believed there was so much complexity to these voting functions!), I find it puzzling that this question doesn't have any up votes. I've upvoted it because, as a relatively new member of the ELU community, I found both the question and the answer gave me a useful insight into how revisions work (and their potential pitfalls), and I suspect it might be a useful resource for others as well.

Comment: @Chappo Thank you. There will always be some random downvotes, even on useful posts. I will just have to accept that without question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing has been revised.

It started from my misunderstanding.

1. @surlawda commented to the answer, "I accidentally hit the "edit" button, but made no changes."
2. I thought @surlawda could roll it back to the original post so that it would not show the editor's username. Sorry that it was my misunderstanding and bad advice. Now I understand only the OP could roll it back. I left this comment. "Hi, Surlawda. So sorry, I didn't know you couldn't roll it back. I think only Steve Cooper could have rolled it back. Anyway, I learned one thing. I am tempted to ask a question about this on Meta. Let me think about it."
3. I think @ab2 wanted to help with the roll-back which seems to have resulted in no change except that it changed the editor's username.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood Rathony's advice to Surlawda and thought it would be easy to fix.  I should have stayed out of it.

Comment: @ab2 I should have stayed out of it, too. :-)